# Android: pass message forward and back between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have 4 activities A,B,C,D. A startsActivityForResult B, B startsActivityForResult C, and C startsActivityForResult D.
I want to do task X (dependent on result from activity B) on activity A. Currently, I use `setResult()`/`onActivityResult()` to pass forward and back the message between activities. This is fragile as activity B/C may finish at any time, in which case the message can not be passed back through `setResult()`. Do we have a better way to do the communication here? without dependency on activity's lifecycle.

Comment: What kind of data are you passing?

Comment: just some flags to indicate the result, may be string or int.

Comment: `This is fragile as activity B/C may finish at any time, in which case the message can not be passed back through setResult()` I am not understanding this, This is the flow for activity life cycle and thats how `setResult()` works. You can find other option like `SharedPreferences` but I think you have to figured out correct way to use `onActivityResult()` and `setResult()` accordingly Activity Life Cycle.

Comment: Because if Activity B/C may finish any time then their should be `onStop()` `onDestroy()` will be called for these two activities and you have to call `setResult()` on this scenario.

Comment: Yes, if B/C destroy, A won't receive the result passed from D. That's why call it fragile. Your solution works, but have to carefully handle all the cases depending on activity lifecycle. That's still not optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are passing simple data types, and you want to persist these data types beyond the lifecycle of an `Activity`, [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) is a solution. Here's an example on how to use the `SharedPreference`

Writing:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

Reading:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

Comment: You could also trying a singleton scenario

Comment: SharedPreferences is too heavy for us. I'm considering a singleton now, will update here and welcome any discussion.

Comment: How do you mean "too heavy?" @user2060386

Answer (score 0):

Activity D should send an `Intent` starting activity A with all of the configuration parameters gathered from B->C->D. You can use an intent flag like `SINGLE_TOP` to return Activity A to the top of the stack. `SharedPreferences` will work, but you'll end up spending about as much time serializing your configuration and returning to activity A as you would just creating an Intent.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325248/4321774) could suit your needs well. Simply send an `Intent` and use the `putExtra()` function to send along extra data with the `Intent`. Then when the `Intent` is received, you can retrieve whatever extra data you sent along.